# How to create a digital certificate and export to .p12 file in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, x509, digital-certificate, pkcs#12

How to create a digital certificate and export to .p12 file in PHP?

I want the .p12 file to have private key included. And also want to check whether the key pair is already issued (logged in database).

I found a function called 'openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file' but don't know where to start. Seems that I need an X509 cert and a private key first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

function dump($Var) {
  echo "<hr/><pre>";
  var_dump($Var);
  echo "</pre><hr/>";
}

function check_errors() {
  echo "<hr/><pre>";
  $Count = 0;
  while (($e=openssl_error_string())!==false) {
    echo $e."<br>";
    $Count++;
  }
  if ($Count==0)
    echo "No error";
  echo "</pre><hr/>";
}

$Configs = array(
  "config" => "e:/progetti/php/openssl/openssl.cfg",
  "digest_alg" => "sha1",
  "x509_extensions" => "v3_ca",
  "req_extensions" => "v3_req",
  "private_key_bits" => 1024,
  "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
  "encrypt_key" => true,
  "encrypt_key_cipher" => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES 
);
$Info = array(
  "countryName" => "VN",
  "stateOrProvinceName" => "Hanoi",
  "localityName" => "Long Bien",
  "organizationName" => "Test Company",
  "organizationalUnitName" => "Test Department",
  "commonName" => "Tester",
  "emailAddress" => "test@gmail.com"
);

$Private_Key = null;
$Unsigned_Cert = openssl_csr_new($Info,$Private_Key,$Configs);
check_errors();
dump($Private_Key);
dump($Unsigned_Cert);

$Signed_Cert = openssl_csr_sign($Unsigned_Cert,null,$Private_Key,365,$Configs);
check_errors();
dump($Signed_Cert);

openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file($Signed_Cert,"test.p12",$Private_Key,"123456");
check_errors();
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a self-signed-certificate:

```
<?php
$dn = array(
    "countryName" => "UK",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "Somerset",
    "localityName" => "Glastonbury",
    "organizationName" => "The Brain Room Limited",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "PHP Documentation Team",
    "commonName" => "Wez Furlong",
    "emailAddress" => "wez@example.com"
);

$privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
$sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, 365);

openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout) and var_dump($csrout);
openssl_x509_export($sscert, $certout) and var_dump($certout);
openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pkeyout, "mypassword") and var_dump($pkeyout);

// Show any errors that occurred here
while (($e = openssl_error_string()) !== false) {
   echo $e . "\n";
}
?>
```